# Prove that the Bessel function $J_n(x)$ satisfied $\int x J_0^2(x) dx = \frac{x^2}{2}[J_0^2(x)+J_1^2(x)]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Prove that the Bessel function $J_n(x)$ satisfied $\int x J_0^2(x) dx = \frac{x^2}{2}[J_0^2(x)+J_1^2(x)]$

I really don't know where to even begin. Any hints or ideas is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where do you integrate?

Comment: I know zero about Bessel functions, so everything should be taken with a grain of salt. I guess you integrate over $\mathbb{R}$. Then the integral on the LHS vanishes (as $xJ_0(x)^2$ is an odd function). Thus, you want to prove that the RHS vanishes as well. It does for $x=0$, so I would try to differentiate the RHS and see that it vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, all we need are two formulas as below: $$\frac{d}{dx}J_0(x)=-J_1(x),$$ $$\frac{d}{dx}J_1(x)=J_0(x)-x^{-1}J_1(x).$$

Now, let's use integration by parts:$$\int xJ_0^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2J_0^2(x)+\int x^2J_0(x)J_1(x).$$

So, we just need to prove: $$\int x^2J_0(x)J_1(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}J_1^2(x).$$

And, this is almost obvious since:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^2}{2}J_1^2(x))=xJ_1^2(x)+x^2J_1(x)(J_0(x)-x^{-1}J_1(x)).$$

---

Edit: The two formulas I mentioned can be found in most typical advanced engineering-mathematics books, for example by Erwin Kreyszig.